# How to split a string into separate words and create the array of these words in C language?

Tags: arrays, c, string

So, the task is the following:

*Find the number of words in the text in which the first and last characters are the same.*

In order to do this, I think I first should split the text and create the array of separate words.

For example, the string is:

*"hello goodbye river dog level"*

I want to split it and get the following array:

*{"hello", "goodbye", "river", "dog", "level"}*

I have the code that splits the string:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   char string[100] = "hello goodbye river dog level";
   // Extract the first token
   char * token = strtok(string, " ");
   // loop through the string to extract all other tokens
   while( token != NULL ) {
      printf( " %s\n", token ); //printing each token
      token = strtok(NULL, " ");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

However, it just prints these words, and I need to append each word to some array. The array shouldn't be of fixed size, because potentially I could add as many elements as the text requires. How to do this?

Comment: How about using a linked list, a bit of overkill maybe, but good practice.

Comment: With the task given I wouldn't split into words. Just unnecessary work.

Comment: Re “In order to do this, I think I first should split the text and create the array of separate words”: No. Go through the string character by character. Figure out if each character is the start of a word (is a letter but is not preceded by a letter), is the end of a word (is a letter but is not followed by a letter), or something else. If it is the start of a word, remember it. If it is the end of a word, check whether it equals the remembered start of a word. If it does, increment a count.

Comment: @SupportUkraine what would you do instead? I just know that in JavaScript language the built-in split function does the job and returns the array. However, I don't know how it's working in the C language

Comment: @ChrisBD Linked lists are rarely ever good practice... They are incredibly slow and tend to be very error-prone if implemented manually.

Comment: "*In order to do this, I think I first should split the text and create the array of separate words.*" -- split the text into words, yes, in the sense of identifying the words within the text.  But create an array of them? Why?  All you need to do is test each word as you discover it to see whether to increment your counter.

Comment: @Alexander you write: "However, I don't know how it's working in the C language" Well, in programming there are always many, many ways to reach the same goal. It's rare that you find something that can only be done in one way. Your task can be solved using `strtok` and `strlen` but that would not be a performance optimal way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any reason to split into words. Just iterate the string while keeping a flag that tells whether you are inside or outside a word (i.e. a state variable). Then have variables for first and last character that you maintain as you iterate. Compare them when you go out of a word or reach end-of-string.

A simple approach could look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count(const char* s)
{
    int res = 0;
    int in_word = 0;
    char first;
    char last;
    
    while(*s)
    {
        if (in_word)
        {
            if (*s == ' ')
            {
                // Found end of a word
                if (first == last) ++res;
                in_word = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                // Word continues so update last
                last = *s;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (*s != ' ')
            {
                // Found start of new word. Update first and last
                first = *s;
                last = *s;
                in_word = 1;
            }
        }
        ++s;
    }
    if (in_word && first == last) ++res;
    return res;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char string[100] = "hello goodbye river dog level";
    printf("found %d words\n", count(string));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
found 2 words
```

Note: Current code assumes that word delimiter is always a space. Further the code doesn't treat stuff like `,` `.` etc. But all that can be added pretty easy.

Comment: I guess gcc would emit a warning that `first` and `last` might be uesd uninitialized although that is obviously not true. But from my experience,  their relation to `in_word` isn't recognized by the compiler

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt well my gcc using "gcc  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic" did not emit warnings

Comment: Just did a bit of testing. It emits a warning if you compile with `-O3 -Wall` (gcc 7.5.0 and 9.4.0). The optimization makes the difference

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Same result here. Compilers, including gcc, sometimes produce false warnings. A simple (but unnecessary) initialization of first and last can "remove" the false warnings.

Comment: of course, I've already mentioned in the first comment that it's a false warning. I just thought that maybe someone else might get that warning too and could be irritated :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple (but naive) implementation based on the existing `strtok` code. It doesn't just count but also points out which words that were found, by storing a pointer to them in a separate array of pointers.

This works since `strtok` changes the string in-place, replacing spaces with null terminators.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char string[100] = "hello goodbye river dog level";
  char* words[10]; // this is just assuming there's not more than 10 words
  size_t count=0;

  for(char* token=strtok(string," "); token!=NULL; token=strtok(NULL, " ")) 
  {
    if( token[0] == token[strlen(token)-1] ) // strlen(token)-1 gives index of last character
    {
      words[count] = token;
      count++;
    }
  }

  printf("Found: %zu words. They are:\n", count);
  for(size_t i=0; i<count; i++)
  {
    puts(words[i]);
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Found: 2 words. They are:
river
level
```

Answer (score 1):

with strtok based on Alexander's code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char string[] = "hello, goodbye; river, dog; level.";
    char *token = strtok(string, " ,;.");
    int counter =0;
    while( token != NULL )
    {
        if(token[0]==token[strlen(token)-1]) counter++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ,;.");
    }
    printf("found : %d", counter);

    return 0;
}
```